# Advanced Installer error in Windows XP

Tags: .net, dll, windows-xp, advanced-installer, windowserror

[image: Windows Xp error]

I added all the required DLLs to the installer even changed the framework to 4.0 so that the application works fine on Windows Xp.I executed the installer on Windows Xp and it gives me the error given the the image above at the end of installation.How should I fix this
Please help

Regards

Comment: what version of AI are you using? also, what SP level has your XP machine, is the crash reproduced constantly on multiple machines?

Comment: Hi bogdan..I am using A 10.8.I fixed up the error.The error was with aero themes not compatible with windows xp and I even changed windows installer version from 5.0 to 4.5 which is supported by xp